# apk update for tablet, still says "Designed for phones"

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I published an update to an apk yesterday (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.heka.tinnitusrev2), and in this update I added support for tablets.

The problem is I still have that ugly "Designed for phones"-brand when I look up the app in Play Store on my tablet.

Here's the steps I've made:

- Updated screenshots for 7" and 10" tablets (Both the localized version and international)
- use sw600dp and sw720dp qualifiers
- updated versioncode and name in manifest
- apk details shows that it supports all sizes small - xlarge

The screenshots for tablets are shown on my tablet so I don't get why it still gets the **Designed for phones** tag.

Anything I missed or is this just something I have to wait out?

EDIT:

I see at [Tablet checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#support-screens) that I should declare:

```
      <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    />
```

but it also says that minSdk should be 11 if I understand correctly(?!) I have minSDK 9 and some users that has those old devices. So I can't have my app < 11 to get rid of that stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the support solved this issue and my tablet app now appears as tablet optimized, this must be done for all apps targeting api < 13:

```
<supports-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
/>
```

Comment: Do you mean after adding the above supports-screens tag, your app gets a tag "Designed for tablets" even with minSDK set to 9?

Comment: exactly, or it doesn't get "designed for phones", App Store on iOS does the "Designed for Tablets" but android just have a naughty tag that says that the developer was too lazy to not develop for tablets ;)

Comment: Still showing my app as "Designed for phones" with above supports-screens tag in manifest and minSDK 15.

Comment: Have you added screenshots for tablet?

Comment: @AndyW Same for me, my app also still shows "Designed for Phones"; I have added above support-screens and also only added 7" and 10" screenshots but no smartphone screenshots in Google Play for that app - but still showing "..for Phones".

Answer (score 0):

You can filter same application for phone and tablets also.

For phone :-

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



 <compatible-screens>
       <!--  all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
      <!--   all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

For tablet:-

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


           <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

It may help.Thanks!!

Comment: I'm aware of this, it's supported for all screen sizes, both phones and tablets so I don't need the filtering, thank you for answering though!