# Android App for Tablets still showing "Designed for Phones"

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I published an app (http://bit.ly/1GfKsNG) which is meant to be for tablets only.

The AndroidManifest.xml is adjusted in the way:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

and in Google Play, I also only added tablets screenshots (7" and 10") and no smartphone screenshots for the app. Still, the app shows "Designed for Phones" in the Play store.

My `res/` folder structure looks like this:

```
/drawable-hdpi
/drawable-ldpi
/drawable-mdpi
/drawable-xhdpi
/drawable-xxhdpi
/layout
/menu
/values
```

I already checked related questions:

- [apk update for tablet, still says "Designed for phones"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654668/apk-update-for-tablet-still-says-designed-for-phones?s=5|0.4216) -> checked! I have the AndroidManifest.xml like this already
- [My app disappeared from "tablet" google play but still available for phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821518/my-app-disappeared-from-tablet-google-play-but-still-available-for-phone) -> checked! I have the support-screens tag already

So the question is, what's the remaining part that I have overlooked to make the app "Designed for Tablets".

What is also strange is that the Google Play store shows no pending optimization tips for tablet optimisation but tells me that tablet optimisation is already finished (by promoting the app from Alpha test status to production).

[image]

Comment: Your APK is indeed live, but I cannot install it on any of my mobiles. Seems like it works as it should :/ The Console is probably late a few hours?

Comment: @shkschneider I had the app in alpha test mode for many days, updated the apk many time and already only available on my tablets as well, not available on my Nexus4 smartphone, but still, then I go to the Play store with my tablet in order to download it, I still see the "Designed for Phones", and it's there already for a couple of days (at least in alpha test status). App went to production today. Not sure, maybe there is a delay and also a difference between alpha test and production mode. The app is not available on the smartphone is because of the support-screens tag. But still not enough

Comment: ... to hide the "Designed for phones" it seems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can request a manual review according to [this article](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html). Specifically, it states:

> If the Optimization Tips page lists "To Do" issues that you feel don't apply to your app or affect its quality on tablets, please notify us using the [Designed for Tablets Contact Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq). We will review your app and update your Optimization Tips page as appropriate.

I also had the same problem a few months ago, so I used the contact form to request a manual review. They responded pretty quickly and told me that my app was in fact "designed for tablets".

Comment: Thanks for the info and link. I just gave it a try and hope they respond soon.

Answer (score 0):

you can also limit the smallest supported screen size by adding the following line:

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
   android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put some tablet screens for Google Play app description.