# How to solve saying "designed for phones" in playstore

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

I am particularly design for tablet.How to avoid this.

My code snippet for support tag's

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

in playstore  i have given screenshot 7 & 10 inches of tablet.

How to solve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u following design for tablet then use xml folder layout-large as inside res folder then should avoid design for phones.

I'm apply to app for design to tablet to play console this article https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq.

I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719442/android-app-for-tablets-still-showing-designed-for-phones)

And also ur drawbles using ldpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi uses and other information need then Optimization tips in play store from get it.

User Acquistion----->Optimation Tips from details get ur app.